# HTML5 Banner using Google Web Designer

Tags: html, google-ads-api, banner, google-web-designer

I have create a html5  banner using Google Web Designer following pretty much all the guidelines (https://support.google.com/webdesigner/answer/3261498?hl=en&ref_topic=3261495&rd=1).

I published it locally and uploaded to google adwords campaign as an Image add. In my banner there is a simple form for the user to enter basic details and submit it. So i have just one event on submit button. All good so far. After i uploaded the banner to google adwords, when i tested the banner the whole banner is clickable for some reason. Somehow google is appending a click event on the whole banner.

But according to docs (https://support.google.com/adwordspolicy/answer/176108?hl=en)

> "HTML5 ads that are not created in Google Web Designer are, by
>   default, clickable on the entire area of the ad."

I used google web designer for this specific reason still i see the entire area clickable. Any ideas or suggestions or references would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Code view, add a higher `z-index` to the submit button so that it sits above the exit element.

Answer (score 0):

> I published it locally and uploaded to google adwords campaign as an Image add.

I think you should try to find a way to not upload as an Image Ad.

Answer (score 0):

Google Adwords requires an exit/destination URL when you upload an ad on their platform disregarding what type of ad you upload.
That URL is assigned to your whole ad.

What you need is DoubleClick account. DoubleClick for advertisers will allow you specific button exits/destination URLs.